# How to access first value of mysqli_fetch_row?

Tags: php, mysqli, percentage

I'm trying to generate the percentage of times people chose one option to a total amount of records, my biggest problem encountered is that it does not allow me to do operations, since my query results are in ROW format ... I need to know how to convert those rows to a calculable variable.

This is my code...

```
$bandparce = $conexao->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM registro1 WHERE valor1= 'led-zeppelin'");
$pontosazul = $azulparcial->fetch_row();
echo '', $pontosazul[0];
echo "<br>";

$azultotal = $conexao->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM registro1 WHERE `id` ");
$totalcores1 = $azultotal->fetch_row();
echo '', $totalcores1[0];

$VARFINAL1 = ($pontosazul * 100) / ($totalcores1); //This is the string that doens't work
echo '', $VARFINAL1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$totalcores1` is an array, you can't use it in mathematical operations, nor convert it to a number, same goes for `$pontosazul`. You probably want the first element in those arrays, which you access like this:

```
$VARFINAL1 = ($pontosazul[0] * 100) / ($totalcores1[0]); 
echo $VARFINAL1;
```

Also, why in the world are you echoing an empty string before outputting those variables?

```
echo '', $totalcores1[0];
```

Just do:

```
echo $totalcores1[0];
```

It's exactly the same thing.